# Arduinoに複数のファイルが一斉に書き込まれてエラーになってしまう

Tags: macos, vscode, arduino

VScodeでArduino nanoに書き込みをしたいです。環境はMacOS,VScodeです。エラーは以下のような時に起こります。

Arduino nanoに送るファイルをVScodeで書き、Arduinoという名のフォルダに保存し実行します。このフォルダにファイルが一つしかなければ、問題なくArduino nanoは動きます。
しかし、フォルダにファイルがすでにある場合、その二つのファイルが書き込まれてエラーが起こります。こちらの解決策を教えて下さい。

どういったエラー文なのかは、例を挙げて紹介します。

例：Lチカを二つ書いてみる

以下をL1と名付けます。

```
int led=5;

void setup(){
    pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){

    digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    delay(1000);

}
```

以下をL2と名付けます。

```
int j=4;

void setup(){
    pinMode(j,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){

    digitalWrite(j,HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(j,LOW);
    delay(500);

}
```

L1を実行してみますと、以下のように「L2でもうloopは使ったでしょ」というように怒られます。

```
/Users/SpaceTAKA/L2.ino: In function 'void setup()':
L2:5:6: error: redefinition of 'void setup()'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino におけるスケッチは **ディレクトリ (フォルダ) 単位** で管理されているようなので、今回の場合なら L1 と L2 を別々のフォルダに分けて保存してみてください。

Comment: ということは、やはりVScodeではワーキングフォルダ一つあたり、一つのファイルしか保存できないのですね

Answer (score -1):

フォルダひとつあたり複数のファイルが問題なのではなく、
複数のファイルで、同じ関数を定義しているのが問題です
関数定義が重複してなければ、普通に複数のファイルで構築できます

Comment: ですがそれだと、void setupyやloopが一度しか使えないことになりませんか？

Comment: そういうことです。
なので、必要な処理は関数などにまとめて、setupなりloopなりで一括して実行する必要があります